# ZF2 Passing Route To Form Element

Tags: php, forms, routes, zend-framework2, element

I am creating a form which needs dynamic options based on the **route** value of **survey_question_reference**

```
'main-surveyquestions'=> [
    'type'    => 'segment',
    'options' => [
        'route'       => '/survey-questions[/:survey_question_reference][/:answer]',
        'constraints' => [
            'survey_question_reference' => '[0-9]*',
            'answer' => '(answer)',
        ],
        'defaults'    => [
            'controller' => 'Main\Controller\Main',
            'action'     => 'surveyquestions'
        ]
    ]
],
```

This is the `Form` code which calls the `FormElement`:

```
/**
 * Init
 */
public function init()
{
    /**
     * Survey Answer
     */
    $this->add(
        [
            'type'       => 'Main\Form\Element\SurveyAnswerRadio',
            'name'       => 'survey_answer',
            'options'    => [
                'label' => 'survey_answer'
            ],
            'attributes' => [
                'id' => 'survey_answer'
            ]
        ]
    );
}
```

The following is the code from the Form Element.  Where I have hard coded **'sqReference' => '1'** the **1** needs to be replaced with the value of **survey_question_reference** from the route.

```
namespace Main\Form\Element;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Zend\Form\Element\Radio;

/**
 * Class SurveyAnswerRadio
 *
 * @package Main\Form\Element
 */
class SurveyAnswerRadio extends Radio
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManager $entityManager
     */
    protected $entityManager;

    /**
     * @param EntityManager $entityManager
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    /**
     * Get Value Options
     *
     * @return array
     *
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    public function getValueOptions()
    {
        $array = [];

        $result = $this->entityManager
            ->getRepository('AMDatabase\Entity\TheVerse\SA')
            ->findBy(
                [
                    'sqReference' => '1'
                ],
                [
                    'surveyAnswer' => 'ASC'
                ]
            );

        if (is_array($result) && count($result) > '0') {
            /**
             * @var \AMDatabase\Entity\TheVerse\SA $val
             */
            foreach ($result as $val) {
                $array[$val->getReference()] = $val->getSurveyAnswer();
            }
        }

        return $array;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest to change approach. First do not try to extends Radio Element which is not necessary at all. You can do same in your Form Class. Second your entity manager also not work in Radio/Form class until your find mechanism to pass.

So I would suggest solutions like below.

First register your form class into as factory in module.config.php

```
'form_elements' => array(
    'factories' => array(
         'Main\Form\YourFormName' => function($sm) {
            $form = new Form\YourFormName();
            $form->setEntityManager($sm->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager'));
            $form->setServiceLocator($sm->getServiceLocator());
            return $form;
         },
     ),
),
```

Then implement entityManager and serviceLocator into your form class.

```
use DoctrineModule\Persistence\ObjectManagerAwareInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class YourFormName extends Form implements ObjectManagerAwareInterface, ServiceLocatorAwareInterface
{
    protected $entityManager;
    protected $serviceLocator;

    public function setServiceLocator(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $this->serviceLocator = $serviceLocator;
    }

    public function getServiceLocator()
    {
        return $this->serviceLocator;
    }
    public function setEntityManager(ObjectManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function getEntityManager()
    {
        return $this->entityManager;
    }
```

Then in init method you have serviceLocator/entityManager is already initialized.

```
public function init()
{
    $routeMatch = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Application')->getMvcEvent()->getRouteMatch();

    $array = [];

    $result = $this->entityManager
        ->getRepository('AMDatabase\Entity\TheVerse\SA')
        ->findBy(
            [
                'sqReference' => $routeMatch->getParam('survey_question_reference')
            ],
            [
                'surveyAnswer' => 'ASC'
            ]
        );

    if (is_array($result) && count($result) > '0') {
        /**
         * @var \AMDatabase\Entity\TheVerse\SA $val
         */
        foreach ($result as $val) {
            $array[$val->getReference()] = $val->getSurveyAnswer();
        }
    }

     $this->add(
    [
        'type'       => 'Zend\Form\Element\Radio',
        'name'       => 'survey_answer',
        'options'    => [
            'label' => 'survey_answer',
            'value_options' => $array,
        ],
        'attributes' => [
            'id' => 'survey_answer',

        ]
    ]
);
```

Comment: `$routeMatch->getParam('survey_question_reference')` not `$routeMatch->getParam('answer')`, he said  "_needs to be replaced with the value of `survey_question_reference` from the route_".

Comment: Yes, my mistake, changed.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looknig for is to **inject** the `survey_question_reference` parameter to your `FormElement`. You could do that as suggested by @kuldeep.kamboj in his answers. But if you don't want to change your approach and keep your custom `SurveyAnswerRadio` element, you have to make some fiew changes in your code :

1. Make `SurveyAnswerRadio` implements `Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface` so that you could implement `setServiceLocator` and `getServiceLocator`, which are required by the ServiceManager to automatically inject the service locator when the element is instantiated.
2. Your form should also implements `Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface`.
3. Implement the `getFormElementConfig` method in your `Module.php`.

Let’s look through the code now. You'll have something like this :

*SurveyAnswerRadio :*

```
class SurveyAnswerRadio extends Radio implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface
{
   //Add these two methods

   public function setServiceLocator(ServiceLocatorInterface $sl)
   {
      $this->serviceLocator = $sl;
   }

   public function getServiceLocator()
   {
      return $this->serviceLocator;
   }

   public function getValueOptions()
   {
    $array = [];
    $serviceManager = $this->serviceLocator->getServiceLocator();
    $em = $serviceManager->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
    $sqReference = $serviceManager->get('application')->getMvcEvent()
                  ->getRouteMatch()->getParam('survey_question_reference');

    $result = $em->getRepository('AMDatabase\Entity\TheVerse\SA')
                 ->findBy(
                        ['sqReference' => $sqReference],
                        ['surveyAnswer' => 'ASC']
                  );

    if (is_array($result) && count($result) > '0') {
        foreach ($result as $val) {
            $array[$val->getReference()] = $val->getSurveyAnswer();
        }
    }

    return $array;
  }
}
```

*Module.php :*

Implement the `getFormElementConfig` method as follows. This allows the class `ModuleName\Form\Element\SurveyAnswerRadio` to be instantiated, or invoked, with the alias `SurveyAnswerRadio`.

```
class Module implements FormElementProviderInterface
{

 // other stuff .....

public function getFormElementConfig()
{
    return array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'SurveyAnswerRadio' => 'ModuleName\Form\Element\SurveyAnswerRadio'
        )
    );
}
}
```

No changes needed in the Form `init` method let it as it is.

Note that in your controller, you'll have to instantiate the `Form` via the `FormElementManager` :

```
$formManager = $this->serviceLocator->get('FormElementManager'); 
$form = $formManager->get('ModuleName\Form\YourForm');
```

Please see more details in the [documentation](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.form.advanced-use-of-forms.html#handling-dependencies)

See also this [post](http://www.haclong.org/en/node/98) which exaplains how to manage dependencies within a custom `Select` Element in Form.